# How to create a custom binding for an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

*Okay, the title of the question kind of suggests one solution I've been considering but here is my issue and I'm open to suggestions.*

I have a view model similar to this (although VASTLY simplified):

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([new Person('fred'), new Person('Joe')]),
    name: ko.observable('hello world')  
};

function Person(name)
{
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
    this.Parent = ko.observable();
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Whenever a `Person` is added to items I want to automatically set it's `Parent` property to the thing it is being added to. (In my real application, this is a deeply hierarchical structure so I can't just hardcode the parent).

I was considering writing a customer binding to make my own observableArray. Whenever anything was added to it, the custom binding would set the `Parent` property. I've looked at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html but this seems to only deal with normal observable properties.

**So how would I do this or is there a better way of achieving this that I am missing?**

Thanks!

Comment: I like the answer below, but otherwise you could choose to pass the parent into the Person constructor and set it during creation.

Comment: My only problem with that is in the real solution a 'Person' can have child 'Person's and so on and so on and I allow the items in the hierarchy to be moved around (using your drag and drop solution funnily enough, Ryan!). So I need to alter the Parent property on already existing Person objects as they get moved around.

Comment: I see.  A subscription on the observableArray that verifies the correct Parent would probably be the easiest.  Would likely not cause any performance issues unless you get into large numbers in your array.   Otherwise, here is a sample that is a quick sample that shows defining a callback to work with the sortableList where the callback receives the item, the old parent, and the new parent.  Might be an option for you. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/pNMYS/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A custom binding would be the wrong thing to do. The binding determines **how** an observable is bound to a DOM element, for example the `value` binding will keep the value of a form field in sync with an observable, the `visible` binding will hide or show a DOM element depending on the observable's value.

The fact that you are setting a property on the Person when it is added to a collection is an implementation detail your user interface should not know about. My suggestion would be to subscribe to the observableArray and set the Parent property manually when a Person is added. In code:

```
 viewModel.items.subscribe(function(new_array) {
   for (var i=0 ; i < new_array.length ; ++i) {
     if (!new_array[i].Parent())
       new_array[i].Parent(items);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Was typing pretty much the same thing.  Subscribe, check if the parent is set, and if not, set it.  Same thing works well for maintaining an index on observableArray items.